# airflow - How to run dags waiting on past succhi ess

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have configured a dag in such a way that if current instance has failed next instance won't run. However, the problem is.

**Problem**
let's say past instance of the task is failed and current instance is in waiting state. Once I fix the issue how to run the current instance without making past run successful. I want to see the history when the task(dag) failed.

**DAG**

```py
dag = DAG(
    dag_id='test_airflow',
    default_args=args,
    tags=['wealth', 'python', 'ml'],
    schedule_interval='5 13 * * *',
    max_active_runs=1,
    )

run_this = BashOperator(
    task_id='run_after_loop',
    bash_command='lll',
    dag=dag,
    depends_on_past=True
    )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could trigger a task execution via [cli](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/cli-ref#run) using `airflow run`

There are two arguments that may help you:

- `-i, --ignore_dependencies` - Ignore task-specific dependencies, e.g. upstream, depends_on_past, and retry delay dependencies
- `-I, --ignore_depends_on_past` - Ignore depends_on_past dependencies (but respect upstream dependencies)

Comment: is there a way I can do it from UI. note everyone has access to backend server

Comment: Well, your settings are somehow contradicting. On the one end you set `depends_on_past=True` to stop further execution of the DAG once it fails, on the other end you want it to execute it again once you applied a fix outside of Airflow - how should Airflow recognize this? 

You may are able to set the the current DAG run (the one that is in state running) on a state of success, this should create a task instance, and then you may can retrigger this task instance from the interface.